# How to update ListView from firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am using firebase to retrieve some data as array of string and display it in list view.

The problem is I have the firebase in a separate class so I need to know how to update my listview in MainActivity

This is my database class

```
    public void GetAllOsr (final ArrayList<String>names){

    // initialize firestore
    firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    //Collection (osar) -> all documents
    firebaseFirestore.collection("Osar").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()){
                // for all documents in it get field name and store it in the arraylist
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                    String name = document.getString("Name");
                    names.add(name);
                }
            }
        }

    });
}
```

and this is my MainActivity

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    final ArrayList<String> osarName = new ArrayList<>();
    dataBaseController.GetAllOsr(osarName);

    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, osarName);
    osar_list.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

Comment: Use FirestoreRecyclerAdapter. Great tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vMnCU6KKHd4&list=PLrnPJCHvNZuDrSqu-dKdDi3Q6nM-VUyxD).

Comment: Have you tried to sue `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` inside the for loop? Does it work this way? Please responde with @AlexMamo

Answer (score 0):

So, if they're in separate classes you need some way to *expose* the ability to update a `ListView`. For example, in one class you could use a "getter" to make the `ListView` and it's datasource visible to the outside world, i.e.

```
public final ListView getMyListView() {
  return this.mListView;
}

publc final List<String> getMyListViewDataSource() {
  return this.mListViewDataSource;
}
```

This would allow you to `append` items to the `mListViewDataSource`, and once you're finished, call `notifyDatasetChanged()` on the `ListView`'s `Adapter` to force Android to recognize the content of the list has changed.

However, this wouldn't be *ideal*. This is because anywhere in your application, you'd be able to access the contents of the `List` and change it arbitrarly, which leads to problems as your application begins to grow. It becomes unmaintainable.

So, what you should do is expose an "event"-style interface in your class, i.e.

```
public final void addItemsToListView(final List<String> pItems) {
  // update the internal list
  // refresh the list
}
```

Since this "hides", or *encapsulates*, the actual contents of the `List`, you'll find that your application will grow a lot easier, since lots of distributed logic around the app don't depend on knowing what the contents of the `List` is. You're just forcing the *protocol*, that outsiders **may only add** to the `List`.

Applications to grow a lot easier/safer after you enforce conventions like these.

Comment: If you please can you add the whole function with the firestore